# Rewrite For Loop Using List Comprehension and Conditional Statements

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, for-loop, list-comprehension

I do not know how to rewrite the following loop using list/dictionary comprehension and conditional statements:

```
for i, sig_id in enumerate(signal_ids):
    if sig_id in aux_dict.keys():
        aux_dict[sig_id] = signal_values[i]
```

`signal_ids` and `signal_values` lists have same size. First element of one list corresponds to the first of the other list, and so on.

Comment: What have you attempted? If you know what a dict comprehension is I imagine you're somewhat familiar with the syntax?

Comment: Keep in mind that the dictionary comprehension makes a new dictionary.  It does not modify an existing one.

Comment: @Mitch The goal is to save signal values by using their ids to a dictionary. Values will be updated in the dictionary when they have changed from previous iteration. In each iteration, `signal_ids` and `signal_values` have new data. I am familiar with comprehension alone, but sometimes using it with conditionals is a bit hard to visualize for me.

Comment: @hpaulj That is true! good point! hence it is not possible to achieve what I want as aux_dict is already defined right?

Comment: Best you could do is use `update` to copy the new dictionary to the existing afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
aux_dict = {sig_id: signal_values[i] for i, sig_id in enumerate(signal_ids) if sig_id in aux_dict.keys()}
```

Comment: Not sure if you noticed but your answer is seemingly identical to CoryKramer's posted several minutes ago.

Comment: you can see the last 'aux_dict.keys()', it is different

Comment: Oh you're right I didn't notice that - except you don't have to call `.keys()`, and doing so is much slower - so your answer is second and worse.

Comment: I am quite beginner with all of this, so why it is better to not include `.keys()`? @Mitch

Comment: Every cycle, reduce the calculation at a time.@BSP

Comment: @BSP When you call `.keys()`, you create a list with all the keys on which you perform a linear search with `in`. Just using `in` on the other hand will use the dictionaries hashing.

Answer (score 1):

You could reproduce this with the following dict comprehension

```
aux_dict = {sig_id : signal_values[i] for i, sig_id in enumerate(signal_ids) if sig_id in aux_dict}
```

Comment: Thank you! your answer really helps me to understand the way dictinoary comprehension and conditional statements work together.